# C++ OpenGL Runtime Error

Tags: c++, opengl, vector

I am currently taking a C++ [tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/OpenGL/index.php) on OpenGL, and I wanted to try to write my own program, which would just draw four vectors. I followed the tutorials model code, only I just modified it a bit. Here are the files inside of my project:

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Render.h"
#include <iostream>

void runMainLoop(int val);

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, args); //Starts OpenGL
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE); //Creates a double buffered display window
    glutInitWindowSize(screenWidth, screenHeight); //Sets window size(screenWidth and screenHeight are set in Render.h)
    glutCreateWindow("Display"); //Creates window
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutTimerFunc(1000 / screenFPS, runMainLoop, 0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void runMainLoop(int val)
{
    render();
    glutTimerFunc( 1000 / screenFPS, runMainLoop, val );
}
```

Render.cpp:

```
#include "Render.h"

void render()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT ); //Clears screen
    glLoadIdentity();
    glBegin( GL_QUADS ); //Vectors
        glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
        glVertex2f(-1.f, -1.f);
        glVertex2f(1.f, -1.f);
        glVertex2f(1.f, 1.f);
        glVertex2f(-1.f, 1.f);
    glEnd(); //End of vectors
    glutSwapBuffers(); //Drawing (This swaps the already-drawn memory with the current display of vectors. This is so you don't get a live draw, which the user would be able to see.)
}
```

Render.h:

```
#ifndef RENDER_H
#define RENDER_H
#include "OpenGLlib.h"
int screenWidth = 500;
int screenHeight = 500;
int screenFPS = 60;
void render();
#endif
```

and finally my OpenGL library, OpenGLlib.h:

```
#ifndef OPENGLLIB_H
#define OPENGLLIB_H
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#endif
```

The issue is in the building process, here is the error that comes up in the Build Log:

```
obj\Debug\Render.o:Render.cpp:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `screenWidth'
obj\Debug\Main.o:Main.cpp:(.data+0x0): first defined here
obj\Debug\Render.o:Render.cpp:(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `screenHeight'
obj\Debug\Main.o:Main.cpp:(.data+0x4): first defined here
obj\Debug\Render.o:Render.cpp:(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `screenFPS'
obj\Debug\Main.o:Main.cpp:(.data+0x8): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

I do not see any other sceenWidth, screenHeight, and screenFPS definitions in my code. Is the compiler reading more files than just the ones in my project? I am using Code::Blocks by the way.

Comment: You are including the header in both Main.cpp and Render.cpp. Defining variables like that in a header file is a bad idea ...

Comment: That's...not a *runtime* error.

Comment: My bad, it's a _compile_ error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Render.h is included by two files and has three variables not declared extern. This means that each translation unit (*.o file) gets a global instance of the variables in the header. This is not good, as the linker can't resolve this nicely; each translation unit will use it's local copy in all of its code, so it can't get rid of one. It also can't keep both, since they have a name conflict.

What you want is to change Render.h to

```
#ifndef RENDER_H
#define RENDER_H
#include "OpenGLlib.h"
extern int screenWidth;
extern int screenHeight;
extern int screenFPS;
void render();
#endif
```

and in main.c

```
#include "Render.h"
#include <iostream>

int screenWidth = 500;
int screenHeight = 500;
int screenFPS = 60;

void runMainLoop(int val);

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, args); //Starts OpenGL
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE); //Creates a double buffered display window
    glutInitWindowSize(screenWidth, screenHeight); //Sets window size(screenWidth and screenHeight are set in Render.h)
    glutCreateWindow("Display"); //Creates window
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutTimerFunc(1000 / screenFPS, runMainLoop, 0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void runMainLoop(int val)
{
    render();
    glutTimerFunc( 1000 / screenFPS, runMainLoop, val );
}
```